# TeXShop sync between reference and .bib file?

Tags: texshop, pdfsync

TeXShop syncs well between the .tex file and the preview for the main text. But when I sync in the reference section, it goes to the .bbl file entry instead of the .bib file entry. Can it go to the .bib file entry instead?

Comment: Sync TeX can only deal with files used directly by the typesetting engine. The .bib file is used by bibtex/biber to produce the .bbl file and that is the only connection to the typesetting engine.